# The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webrequest

why I am getting "The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error." 
this error this my code

```
    public override object Request()
    {
        Response = "";
        RequestTime = DateTime.Now;
        var url = _service.Url;
        HttpWebResponse responseObj = null;
        try
        {
            Uri requestUri = null;
            Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out requestUri);



            CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
            NetworkCredential networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("username",
                                         "password", url);
            Uri uri = new Uri(url);
            cc.Add(uri, "Basic", networkCredential);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(uri);

            request.Proxy = new WebProxy(url);
            request.Credentials = cc;

            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;


            Response = request.GetResponse();


        }
        catch (Exception x)
        {

            Logger.append(x.Message, Logger.ERROR);
        }
        Duration = DateTime.Now.Subtract(RequestTime).TotalMilliseconds;
        return Response;
   }
```

I tried the url direct from the browser and it's working.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with the debugger?

Comment: Check the event log on the server.

Comment: yes and I got this error

Comment: If it is a POST, where are your forms???

Comment: Do you really want to set the proxy to be the server you're trying to connect to?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply navigate to the url in a browser, the httpMethod will be `GET` but you're setting it to `Post` in your code. That might be why it works in the browser but not you code.

i'd say your code it probably fine, but is the web site supporting posts to that url?

Comment: thanks for your answer but I have tried both get and post and I am receiving the same error.